# WooCommerce cart validation: check that specific product is always added before other products

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, cart

**Description:**

I have use case where I need to check if a specific product has been added to cart before customer adds another products to cart.

**Background:**

We are renting products out based on packages(which are products). Packages include multiple products and products do not have price, packages do. So basically you would need to add a package(with price) and products(with no price) to cart.

**Problem:**

At the moment customers can add products before packages and they can continue to shopping cart with total zero.

**Some of the progress what I have:**

```php
if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() )
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
    // now i would need to check if cart consists a package
```

---

And i could solve adding product to cart with no package in cart like this:

```php
if (WC()->cart->is_empty() )
//then don't add product to cart, tell customer to add package first.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook
- Comment with explanation added in the code

```php
function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    // Product (ID) in cart
    $product_first_in_cart = 30;
    
    // Compare
    if ( $product_first_in_cart != $product_id ) {
        // Set variable
        $in_cart = false;
        
        // Cart NOT empty
        if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
            // Loop trough cart
            foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                // Search for the specific product
                if ( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $product_first_in_cart ) {
                    // Found, break loop
                    $in_cart = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // NOT in cart
        if ( ! $in_cart ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Please add product "A" before adding other products', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            $passed = false;
        }
    }

    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

Comment: And if i want to add multiple product ids to $product_first_in_cart = 30, then i need to modify if ( $cart_item['data']->get_id() == $product_first_in_cart ) part?

Comment: for example, if $product_first_in_cart = array(30,45,45);

Comment: for that you can use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). 
Adjusting the code depends on whether, for example, 1 of those products must be present in the shopping cart or all products must be present in cart before other products can be added. 
If you can't figure it out, feel free to ask a new question referring to this one. However, don't forget to add the attempts you've made to your new question so that it shows the necessary commitment. Regards